# Table shows DISTINCT information when I tell it not to?

Tags: sql, oracle

For some reason I keep getting an output with `DISTINCT` information. I am trying to understand `JOINS` and I am not sure why I am getting this output:

```
MANUFACTURE                              MODEL         
---------------------------------------- ---------------
Chrysler Corp.                           200            
Ford Motor Company                       300            
General Motors                           200 Convertible
Honda                                    Durango        
Nisan                                    Avenger        
Toyota                                   Town & Country 
                                         4Runner        
                                         Altima         
                                         Caliber        
                                         Camry          
                                         Challenger     
                                         Charger        
                                         Colorado       
                                         Corolla        
                                         Cruze          
                                         EX37           
                                         Grand Caravan  
                                         Journey        
                                         Malibu         
                                         Orlando        
                                         Pathfinder     
                                         Prius          
                                         Q50            
                                         Q60            
                                         Q70            
                                         Rogue SL       
                                         Sonic          
                                         Versa Note     

 28 rows selected
```

Here is what i have tried and above is the output:

```
SELECT MANUFACTURENAME AS "MANUFACTURE", MODELNAME AS "MODEL"
FROM TBLMANUFACTURE
FULL JOIN TBLMODEL
ON TBLMANUFACTURE.MANUFACTUREID = TBLMODEL.MODELID
ORDER BY MANUFACTURENAME, MODELNAME ASC;
```

What I am trying to do is list all of the manufacturer names with their associated models.

**Scripts to Repro the issue:**

```
DROP TABLE  tblOptionDetail;
DROP TABLE  tblOption;
DROP TABLE  tblVehicle;
DROP TABLE  tblModel;
DROP TABLE  tblBrand;
DROP TABLE  tblManufacture;


CREATE TABLE tblManufacture
(
ManufactureID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
ManufactureName CHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE tblBrand
(
BrandID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
ManufactureID NUMBER(38),
BrandName CHAR(40),
FOREIGN KEY (ManufactureID) REFERENCES tblManufacture(ManufactureID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblModel
(
ModelID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
BrandID NUMBER(38),
ModelName CHAR(40),
FOREIGN KEY (BrandID) REFERENCES tblBrand(BrandID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblVehicle
(
VehicleID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
ModelID NUMBER(38),
VehicleYear NUMBER(38) CHECK (VehicleYear BETWEEN 1900 and 3000),
VehicleKM NUMBER(38) CHECK (VehicleKM BETWEEN 0 and 100000000),
VehiclePrice NUMBER(38) CONSTRAINT carprice CHECK (VehiclePrice BETWEEN 0 and 1000000),
FOREIGN KEY (ModelID) REFERENCES tblModel(ModelID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblOption
(
OptionID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
OptionDesc CHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE tblOptionDetail
(
OptionID NUMBER(38),
VehicleID NUMBER(38),
PRIMARY KEY (OptionID, VehicleID),
FOREIGN KEY (OptionID) REFERENCES tblOption(OptionID),
FOREIGN KEY (VehicleID) REFERENCES tblVehicle(VehicleID)
);


-- populate the Manufacture table

INSERT ALL 
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES (1,'Chrysler Corp.')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES(2,'General Motors')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES(3,'Ford Motor Company')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES(4,'Toyota')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES (5,'Honda')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES (6,'Nisan')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate the Brand table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (1,1, 'Chrysler')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (2,1, 'Dodge')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (3,1, 'Jeep')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (4,2, 'Chevrolet')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (5,2, 'Buick')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (6,2, 'Cadillac')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (7,2, 'GMC')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (8,4, 'Toyota')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (9,6, 'Nissan')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (10,6,'Infiniti')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate the Model table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (1,1, '200')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (2,1, '200 Convertible')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (3,1, '300')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (4,1, 'Town'||' & '||'Country')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (5,2, 'Durango')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (6,2, 'Avenger')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (7,2, 'Challenger')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (8,2, 'Charger')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (9,2, 'Caliber')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (10,2, 'Grand Caravan')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (11,2, 'Journey')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (12,4, 'Sonic')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (13,4, 'Cruze')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (14,4, 'Orlando')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (15,4, 'Colorado')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (16,4, 'Malibu')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (17,8, '4Runner')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (18,8, 'Prius')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (19,8, 'Camry')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (20,8, 'Corolla')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (21,9,'Rogue SL')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (22,9, 'Versa Note')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (23,9, 'Pathfinder')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (24,9, 'Altima')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (25,10, 'Q70')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (26,10, 'Q50')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (27,10, 'Q60')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (28,10, 'EX37')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate Option table

INSERT ALL 
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (1,'Power locks')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (2,'Power windows')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (3,'Air conditioning')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (4,'Heated mirrors')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (5,'Remote keyless entry')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (6,'CD Player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (7,'GPS')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (8,'In-dash DVD player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (9,'Overhead DVD player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (10,'Satellite radio')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (11,'MP3 player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (12,'Antilock braking system')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (13,'Electronic stability system')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (14,'Traction control')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (15,'Cruise control')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (16,'Intelligent cruise control')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (17,'Parking assist system')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (18,'Xenon headlights')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (19,'Aluminum rims')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (20,'AWD')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (21,'Convertable')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (22,'Heated Seats')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate Vehicle table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (1,10, 2010, 45000, 18000)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (2,10, 2010, 65420, 17500)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (3,16, 2004, 143900, 3200)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (4,11, 2010, 38900, 14500)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (5,27,2014,17250,45999)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (6,25,2015,2900,62300)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (7,17,2010,87900,19800)
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate OptionDetail table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (5, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (7, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (8, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (11, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (11, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES  (4,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (8,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (5,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (21,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (22,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1,7)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (4,7)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (5,7)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2,7)
SELECT * FROM dual;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you join `tblManufacture` with `tblBrand` based on `ManufactureID` and then join `tblModel` based on `BrandID`? Currently you're creating a link which will never exist if your database model makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include tblBrand to link the manufacture with model. So regular inner joins:

```
SELECT MANUFACTURENAME AS "MANUFACTURE", MODELNAME AS "MODEL"
FROM TBLMANUFACTURE 
join tblBrand ON TBLMANUFACTURE.ManufactureID = tblBrand.ManufactureID 
JOIN TBLMODEL ON tblBrand.BrandID= TBLMODEL.BrandID
ORDER BY MANUFACTURENAME, MODELNAME ASC;
```

Comment: Ah I see, so that is how you join multiple tables into one. I don't see why you aren't using the keywords `FULL JOIN` or the other `JOINS` instead of just `JOIN` though.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit lazy, `JOIN` is simply the short form of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @AsadMahmood -   "join" is shorthand for "inner join". You very rarely need FULL join; you may need one-sided outer join (such as left outer join) but only if you may have manufacturers with no models at all, and you want to include those manufacturers in the list, with NULL for model. Is that the case?

Comment: Actually while it's not the case you just made me understand `FULL JOINS` a bit better. I had trouble knowing what all the different types of `JOINS` would do and when it would be appropriate to use them. +1 to you.

Comment: Also, it would be MUCH better if you do not use double-quotes on column names; if you do, and you need this as a subquery in something larger, you will have to remember to always write the names with the same capitalization as in the alias. In this case you don't need aliases at all, since you are not changing the names!

Answer (score 2):

The join condition is wrong - why would you "join" (consider "compatible") a model and a manufacturer, if the model_id matches the manufacturer_id?

Rather, you need to join through the brand table (there is no direct reference from model to manufacturer); join model and brand on brand_id and then further join with manufacturer on manufacturer_id.

```
select ma.manufacturename, mo.modelname
from   tblmodel mo join tblbrand       br on mo.brandid = br.brandid
                   join tblmanufacture ma on br.manufactureid = ma.manufactureid
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using full join. Your condition is based on `ON TBLMANUFACTURE.MANUFACTUREID = TBLMODEL.MODELID`
i.e., you are selecting matching data between columns in two tables as well as unmatching columns.

If you need more understanding, just visit this site: https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/joiner-transformation/. The diagrams in the table will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "brand" table for brandid. You can try this code;

```
SELECT manufacturename, modelname
  FROM TBLMANUFACTURE t, tblbrand tt, tblmodel ttt
 where t.manufactureid = tt.manufactureid
   and ttt.brandid = tt.brandid
```

I hope it help you.